# Cox regression latex output equation explanation

Tags: r, interpretation, cox-model

After fitting a Cox model when I export the equation using

w <- latex(f, file='f.tex')
The XB contains a constant which is not one of the beta co-efficient of the predictors in the model. Is this the baseline hazard?

Do I have to include this while calculating the survival probability using the equation S(t)=S(0)exp(βpredictor1*predictor1 + βpredictor2*predictor2 etc.)?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It's going to be hard to answer this unless you show the output from the `latex` output. A Cox model has no intercept and only provides an empirical baseline hazard.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching found out that the latex output of a Cox model equation includes the centering constant, equal to overall mean of X beta.